# GoogleMaps4Rails not centering first marker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails2

I am trying to open my first marker on my map via the gmaps4rails gem.
Using the sidebar example from their page:

```
function createSidebarLi(json) {
                  return ("<li><a>" + json.title + "</a> (" + json.categories + "...)</li>");
              };

              function bindLiToMarker($li, marker) {
                  $li.on('click', function () {
                      handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
                      marker.setMap(handler.getMap()); //because clusterer removes map property from marker
                      marker.panTo();
                      google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
                  })
              };

handler = Gmaps.build('Google');

handler.buildMap({provider: {
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP},
                  internal: {
                      id: 'map_sidebar'}}, function () {

                  var json_array = <%= raw @hash.to_json %>;
                  var markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array);

                  _.each(json_array, function (json, index) {
                      json.marker = markers[index];
                  });
                  createSidebar(json_array);
                  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
                  handler.fitMapToBounds();
              });
```

I am bit confused because of their Version switch. Sometimes it's serviceObject, then it's getServiceObject,-...

I thought something like this

```
marker.infowindow.open(map, marker.serviceObject);
```

or this

```
markers[0].getServiceObject() 
markers[0].panTo()
```

should work?

Can someone please help me out????

Many thanks!

Comment: I dont understand the question

Comment: sorry. Simply wanna know how to open the infowindow of the most first entry on my json_array.

Comment: you have to trigger `click` event on the marker

Comment: yes sure. But How do I reach the markers? I cant find them. So ```markers[0].getServiceObject()``` or my other examples above does not open the map. I got ```undefind``` callbacks. But the map with markers is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this in the `buildMap` callback

```
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[0].getServiceObject(), 'click');
```

Comment: I'm quite new to googlemaps itself and their handling.